# Email Notification With Custom Fields In sugarCRM CE 6.5

Tags: sugarcrm

I have some custom fields in my bug module in CRM. Whenever user create any buy it's send mail to assign_user with some fields like down.

```
mick has assigned a Bug to  Store 51.

Bug Number: 
Subject: Test
Type: 
Priority: High
Status: In Process
Resolution: 
Release: 
Description: testing
Work Log: testing
```

Here I don't need some fields and would like to add some custom fields how it would be possible.?
There is any PHP file for modify or something from admin setting.

Any helps will be appreciate.

Thank You..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the directions under the en_us.notify_template.html section here: http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/05/10/howto-customize-the-assignment-notifications-for-a-custom-module/